# View changes between snapshots - firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Any idea on how to view changes between snapshots of specific collection  in context of  firestore & flutter

Idea is to handle only difference like add/delete/update type.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have :

```
    Firestore.instance.collection("your_collection").snapshots().listen((querySnapShot){

          querySnapShot.documentChanges.forEach((documentChange){
            if (documentChange.type == DocumentChangeType.added){
              print("document: ${documentChange.document.data} added");
            } else if (documentChange.type == DocumentChangeType.modified){
              print("document: ${documentChange.document.data} modified");
            } else if (documentChange.type == DocumentChangeType.removed){
              print("document: ${documentChange.document.data} removed");
            }
          });
    });
```