# How to view changes between snapshots in firestore? | Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

This question was already asked here: [View changes between snapshots - firestore flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041748/view-changes-between-snapshots-firestore-flutter).

The problem is that flutter does not seem like to have the key word '.documentChanges'. It only has the keyword .data() where you just get the data without getting information whether it is add/remove/replace.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_userId).snapshots().listen((event) {
   event.data().forEach((key, value) {});
});
```

There is no event.documentChanges in my flutter project. Do I need another package that I don't know jet? Do I have to downgrade the the firestore sdk to a specific version? How can I do that in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest version, then you should be able to do the following:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().listen((event) {
        event.docChanges.forEach((res){
           if (res.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
                 // added
            }
        });
      });
```

Comment: I am using cloud firestore ^0.14.3+1, but I don't have .docChanges, I  get an error that the function doesn't exist for Documentsnapshot . Do I need an extra import for .docChanges?

Comment: Thank  you I got the issue, the problem was I attached the listener do document and not to the collection users. Thank you